# Stream video to a streaming service with Rtmp

Tags: c#, node.js, streaming, rtmp

I am trying to find information about how Node JS / C# can send a video stream to Twitch, Facebook and Youtube using RTMP. Input would be different format. Image, video or a website. Like a realy tiny OBS.

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve] that shows what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Well i would if i had some code, but i do not know if there is a good library for that or any information how i can do this. I Have google for a while but without any results. So i have no starting point... @dymanoid

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build it yourself then look at [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg).
Now how you capture the a.v.(audio visual) is a different question but ffmpeg can be used to push out a stream(over what protocol im not sure just had a quick browse and didnt see it easily). With ffmpeg you can you have a multitude of options of what you can do I've looked at it before and used it in a project or two and its extremely intuitive and well documented. But if your starting another library to look at is [fluent-ffmpeg for node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) as it puts an easier to use wrapper over the api.
A pre made solution would be [node-rtsp-rtmp-server](https://github.com/iizukanao/node-rtsp-rtmp-server) but again with this it works off of a file like an mp4 in a folder so you would have to alter it for your own purposes.
If you were to do this first find someway to capture your a.v. and connect it to ffmpeg to save the file aswell as transcoding it to whatever filetype you want, then allow this server to stream to your required destination.
If I was you id would have a good luck at opensource repositories like [github](https://github.com/) first and see whats available.
Also just to point out this is just the way to stream(and a breif overview at that) theres also the whole authentication process with the social-media services and all the connection thats needed between your server and the endpoint service.